# polkit not working properly in Ubuntu 16

Tags: permissions, mount, policykit

I have a dual boot, and in order to mount the Windows filesystem from Ubuntu, I had set it up so that I need to type in my password, to prevent me from accidentally mounting a system by clicking the wrong button.

This I did by editing the `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`  file.

In the `[Mounting, checking, etc. of internal drives]` area, I changed `ResultActive=yes` to `ResultActive=auth_admin`

This works fine, when I'm logged with my main (administrator) account.  It asks me for a password every time I try to mount a drive. However, when I log onto my machine as an unprivileged user (which I have set up for security reasons) it behaves differently.

`ResultActive=auth_admin` behaves as `ResultActive=auth_admin_keep`, even if I don't have the `_keep` at the end. It asks me for my administrator account's password, and then remembers it's been entered and doesn't ask again.

In fact, `ResultActive=no` also behaves like `ResultActive=auth_admin_keep` for a non-administrator account. If I'm signed in as an administrator, `no` means `no`, and I can't mount Windows. Not so for a non-administrator, `no` means "ask for your admin's password, and I'll remember that and not ask again".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The file that needs to be modified is:

/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy

The second action, "mount a filesystem on a system device"
has at the bottom:

<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>

which I changed to:

<allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>